# System.ArgumentException: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm keep getting this exception **sometimes** if I start my program not everytime.

```html
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(Object Prompt, MsgBoxStyle Buttons, Object Title)
   at svchost.Form1.VB$StateMachine_39_Form1_Load.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
```

I had this problem last week for 5 hours or something until I reinstalled my PC and then it worked again. I have no clue why this just appears randomly..

I hope someone can help me with that, it doesn't give me any line or code output that's so stupid.

Comment: Edit to remove unacceptable language.

Comment: Why are you using MsgBox? You have the [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox) class available.

Comment: _"it doesn't give me any line or code output"_ - It does actually give you a little bit of information: `at svchost.Form1.VB$StateMachine_39_Form1_Load.MoveNext()` - This indicates that the error occurred in your `Form1_Load` event handler (which appears to be declared `Async`), so you should look at any message boxes in there. If they're not too many, post the code for them here and we can help you examine them. Be sure to include the code for everything that should be displayed in them.